# Recursively splitting off perfect squares for display

Tags: java, recursion

I am attempting to create a recursive method that accepts an integer parameter and prints the first *n* squares
separated by commas, with the odd squares in descending order followed by the even squares in ascending order.

For example, if the input is 8, it should print the following output:

```
49, 25, 9, 1, 4, 16, 36, 64
```

My code so far is:

`s` and `n` have the same values initially, the only difference is that s changes as the code forwards while `n` doesn't change.

```
private static void genSquare(int s, int n) {
    if (s >= 0 && s <= n) {
        if (isOdd(s)) {
            System.out.print(Math.pow(n, 2) + " ");
            genSquare(s - 2, n);
        }
        if (s == 0 || s == 1) {
            genSquare(1, n);
        }
        if (isEven(s)) {
            System.out.print(Math.pow(n, 2) + " ");
            genSquare(s + 2, n);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a while loop version of it, which works perfectly.  I just don't have the recursive version working.

Sample inputs would be using the same number for s and n.

Here is the code for the loop version:

```
private void genLoop(int s, int n) {
    if (isEven(s)) {
        s--;
    }

    while (s <= n) {
        if (s == 1) {
            System.out.print(1 + "  ");
            s++;
        } else if (isOdd(s)) {
            System.out.print(s * s + "  ");
            s -= 2;
        } else if (isEven(s)) {
            System.out.print(s * s + "  ");
            s += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void calculateSquare(int n)
    {
//      odds descending and even ascending
        int t=n;
        if(n<=0)
            return;
         if(n%2==1)
        {
//          Calculate square now and print it also
            System.out.println(n*n);
            calculateSquare(--n);

        }
        else
        {

            calculateSquare(--n);
            System.out.println(t*t);

        }

    }
```

This would do the job.

Comment: Awesome mam, you are really an Algorithmist !!
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Great job @Algorithmist ... now the OP doesn't need to do his homework!  >>Sigh<<

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this statement:

```
    if(s == 0 || s== 1)
        genSquare(1,n);
```

This causes the method to recurse infinitely.  In fact, when you get to the point where `s` is zero or one, you have to make sure that you DON'T call genSquare recursively.

That's enough of a hint for you to figure the rest out for yourself ... and fix any other bugs.

---

In addition, there's a simpler way of squaring an integer ...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

Assume your example where n is equal to 8. The square of 8 should printed last so you probably first should do a recursive call, then print the square of the current number.

Thinking about the task for n=7 the order of things given above should be reverted for odd numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is good example for recursion . Try this it helps u

```
public class RecursionEx {

    static int no = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the Number");
        try 
        {
             no = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
             getSquares(no,0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void getSquares(int number,int count) 
    {
        if(number==1)
        {
            System.out.print(number);
            count=1;
            getSquares(number+1, count);

        }
        else
        {
            if(number%2!=0&&count==0)
            {
                System.out.print(number*number+",");
                getSquares(number-2,0);
                return;
            }
            if(count==0)
            getSquares(number-1,0);

            if(number%2==0&&count==1)
            {
                if(number<=no)
                System.out.print(","+number*number);
                if(number>=no)
                    return;

                getSquares(number+2, count);
            }


        }
    }
}
```